# Configuring window.location.href inginx

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

After login success im calling the following url in script tag window.location.href = "{PageContext.request.contextpath}/welcome" . "welcome" is my controller. Im unable to get inside the " welcome" controller

Comment: ... You need to provide more info or some code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Try to use "${request.contextPath}/welcome" instead of "${PageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome".
It will solve your problem`